# need to filter and first matching element of obect array in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have objected array , came through the rest call , and the data structure looks like below. I need to filter that and get the first matching object. I used a typescript filter and try to find as well but did not return the first matching object. need some expert help to resolve this

```
"products": [
                    {
                        "subProduct": {
                            "Id": "14",          
                            "Type": "Main",
                          
                        }
                      
                    },
                    {
                        "subProduct": {
                            "Id": "2",
                            "Type": "B",
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "subProduct": {
                            "Id": "2",
                            "Type": "B",
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "subProduct": {
                            "Id": "22",
                            "Type": "Main",
                        }
                    }
             
                ]
```

code :

```
const mainProduct = products.find(product => {
 product.subProduct.Type === Type.Main;
 })
```

Comment: The code you posted looks almost correct. Supposing that `Type.Main` is of type string and it has the value `"Main"`, you just need to return the value of the comparison `return product.subProduct.Type === Type.Main;`. Can you try this and see if it works?

Comment: Do you has some like: `export enum Type {Main="Main",B="B",...}`? if yours "types" are numbers, you can create an auxiliar array of strings `["Main","B",...]` and compare `Type==myArray[Type.Main]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `return` inside the find().

Must be:

```js
const mainProduct = products.find(product => {
 return product.subProduct.Type === Type.Main;
})
```

Or without the return:

```js
products.find(product => product.subProduct.Type === Type.Main)
```